# POST XML to REST API using RESTClient in C#

Tags: c#, rest

I need to post XML data to REST API , i am using below code but getting an error

> {"fault":{"faultstring":"Invalid access
> token","detail":{"errorcode":"oauth.v2.InvalidAccessToken"}}}

However , Its perfectly working with Postman tool. Can you please suggest wrong.

```
  public string postVendorPayment(string paymentFile , string accessToken)
    {
        string xml;
        var Bclient = new RestClient("https://testapi.io/ws/rest/d365/v1/creditTransfer/"); // + "?access_token=" + accessToken);

        var request1 = new RestRequest(Method.POST);
        request1.AddParameter("Content-type", "application/xml",ParameterType.HttpHeader);
        request1.AddParameter("application/xml", paymentFile, ParameterType.RequestBody);
        request1.AddParameter("Cache-Control", "no-cache", ParameterType.HttpHeader);
        request1.AddParameter("Authorization", "Bearer " + accessToken);

        IRestResponse response1 = Bclient.Execute(request1);
        var content1 = response1.Content;

        string jsonshipment = content1;
        if (jsonshipment != "")
        {
            XmlDocument docItem = (XmlDocument)JsonConvert.DeserializeXmlNode(jsonshipment, "Channeladvisor");

            xml = docItem.InnerXml.ToString();
        }
        else
        {
            xml = jsonshipment;
        }
        return xml;
    }
```

Comment: I note that for the other two headers, you're explicitly supplying them as `ParameterType.HttpHeader`. How does RestClient treat a parameter without an explicit type?

Comment: Can you please correct my code  , i didn't get you. I am new to C#.

Comment: This line `request1.AddParameter("Authorization", "Bearer " + accessToken);` is missing `ParameterType.HttpHeader` as last argument. You passed this value for Content-Type and Cache-Control headers.

Comment: Thanks , got it done. however , how can i make it more parametric instead of hard code of parameter

Comment: @VishWalia You usually store this information in a secure external parameter store. Then, in the deployment phase, you fetch the key and store it in the environment variable. You can then use it in your code in a testable manner by using the environment variable handler provided by the framework.